# where condition at runtime

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code

```
 DataView res = (from a in dtvw.AsEnumerable()
                         where a.Field<string>(creteriaattributeID) == rightval
                        select a).AsDataView();
```

here , i wanna get the operator ("== ") at runtime is it possible ?

I tried using

```
where a.Field<string>(creteriaattributeID) + operator + rightval
```

operator --> string variable so it wont b possible ... Can you suggest any other methods...

Comment: How do you know which operator should be used? Is it passed in by string?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the `==` operator as function which takes two strings and return bool.
So for example `Func<string, string, bool>`.
Can you just use a variable of this type:

```
Func<string, string, bool> equal = (a,b) => { return a == b; };
Func<string, string, bool> notequal = (a,b) => { return a != b; };

DataView res = (from a in dtvw.AsEnumerable()
                where equal(a.Field<string>(creteriaattributeID), rightval)
                    select a).AsDataView();
```

Comment: its very nice.. but cant i take an operator at runtime? because i need to write many more functions...

Comment: what are the different operators you want to work with? How is an operator different from a custom function? To me this is the same, so I am not sure what your concern is...

Comment: +1 @OP If you want to convert user input to an operator at run time just use a switch statement or equivalent to assign the correct operator to the Func variable.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create and expression dinamically

I.E.

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda1;

if(paramOperator=="=="){
 ParameterExpression stringParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "a");
            ConstantExpression criteriaValue = Expression.Constant(rigthval, typeof(string));
            BinaryExpression comparison= Expression.Equals(stringParam , criteriaValue );
            lambda1 =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
                    comparison,
                    new ParameterExpression[] { stringParam });
}

DataView res = dtvw.AsEnumerable().Where(lamda1.Compile()).AsDataView();
```

Comment: this should work on every .net runtime environment which supports .net LINQ i havent tested but i believe it give you a  good start

Comment: @Abhijith Nayak - this code runs on the server and so the particular browser is completely irrelevant. The same expression would work in a console app or winform app (=no asp.net at all).

Comment: its giving some errors while compiling... can yuo debug this and give running code?

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand the problem, the code compiled perfectly for me.

```
DataTable dtvw = new DataTable();

DataView res = (from a in dtvw.AsEnumerable()
                where a.Field<string>(10) == "12"
                select a).AsDataView();
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to decide at runtime what operator to use.

Comment: okay.. then i would recommend the same solution like you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't that many operators, so why not hardcode it?

```
DataView res;

switch (theOperator)
{
  case "==":
    res = (from a in dtvw.AsEnumerable()
                     where a.Field<string>(creteriaattributeID) == rightval
                    select a).AsDataView();
    break;
  case "!=":
    res= (from a in dtvw.AsEnumerable()
                     where a.Field<string>(creteriaattributeID) != rightval
                    select a).AsDataView();
    break;
  // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are working over LINQ to DataSets. If that's the case, why not use the native DataTable.Select(string) method where you can just pass the operator as a string anyway. The alternative of dynamically building expressions is much more painful. LINQ is much more suited to compile time query than runtime query.